# Determining Best Table Structure for MySQL Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I'm working on a browser-based RPG for one of my websites, and right now I'm trying to determine the best way to organize my SQL tables for performance and maintenance.

Here's my question:

**Does the number of columns in an SQL table affect the speed in which it can be queried?**

I am not a newbie when it comes to PHP or MySQL. I used to develop things with the common goal of getting them to work, but I've recently advanced to the stage where a functional program is not good enough unless it's fast and reliable.

Anyways, right now I have a `members` table that has around 15 columns. It contains information such as the player's username, password, email, logins, page views, etcetera. It doesn't contain any information on the player's progress in the game, however. If I added columns for things such as army size, gold, turns, and whatnot, then it could easily rise to around 40 or 50 total columns.

**Oh, and my database structure IS normalized.**

Will a table with 50 columns that gets constantly queried be a bad idea? Should I split it into two tables; one for the user's general information and one for the user's game statistics?

I know I could check the query time myself, but I haven't actually created the tables yet and I think I'd be better off with some professional advice on this important decision for my game.

Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of columns can have a measurable cost if you're relying on table-scans or on caching pages of table data.  But the best way to get good performance is to create **indexes** to assist your queries.  If you have indexes in place that benefit your queries, then the width of a row in the table is pretty much inconsequential.  You're looking up specific rows through much faster means than scanning through the table.

Here are some resources for you:

- [EXPLAIN Demystified](http://en.oreilly.com/mysql2010/public/schedule/detail/12474)
- [More Mastering the Art of Indexing](http://www.slideshare.net/matsunobu/more-mastering-the-art-of-indexing)

Based on your caveat at the end of your question, you *already know* that you should be measuring performance and only fixing code that has problems.  Don't try to make premature optimizations.

Unfortunately, there are no one-size-fits-all rules for defining indexes.  The best set of indexes need to be designed custom for the queries that you need to be fastest.  It's hard work, requiring a lot of analysis, testing, and taking comparative measurements for performance.  It also requires a lot of reading to understand how your given RDBMS technology uses indexes.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with those resources. Since I will almost always be querying the table to look for the user's id (which is the primary key), then it should be no problem for me to have a lot of columns based on your response.

Thanks again, now I can proceed with my development. :)